# Autenticar usuário de forma eficiente e rápida (sem contratempos, Identity x Manual)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, login

Preciso criar um sistema <strike>divertido</strike> que utilize uma validação (usuário,senha). Tenho experiência com WebForm, comecei já estudei um pouco de MVC mas ainda não me sinto seguro para criar uma aplicação completa com MVC.

Para a validação pensei em utilizar o Identity, pois pelo que vi torna as coisas mais fáceis, porém, não vi do zero, fiz um exemplo e algumas alterações <strike>mínimas</strike>. E aí fiquei na dúvida, se vale a pena aprender a utilzar o Identity durante a criação desse projeto ou usar uma menos sofisticada,como armazenar em sessão ou cookie.

`A preocupação principal é ter problemas com o Idntity que possam acabar tomando tempo.`

Ainda estou em dúvida se fiz certo em publicar a pergunta aqui, em todo caso
se não identificar uma resposta e apenas discussões, vou remover a pergunta.
Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: O melhor seria você aprender o MVC mesmo. O Identity nem foi escrito para Web Forms.

Comment: Minto. Foi sim. Vou colocar uma resposta pra você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Para a validação pensei em utilizar o Identity, pois pelo que vi torna as coisas mais fáceis, porém, não vi do zero, fiz um exemplo e algumas alterações <strike>mínimas</strike>. E aí fiquei na dúvida, se vale a pena aprender a utilzar (sic) o Identity durante a criação desse projeto ou usar uma menos sofisticada,como armazenar em sessão ou cookie.

[Existe um projeto que ensina a usar o Identity com o Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project). Acho que vale a pena dar uma olhada.

> A preocupação principal é ter problemas com o Idntity (sic) que possam acabar tomando tempo.

Normalmente o uso do ASP.NET Identity é muito simples, principalmente se você iniciar o projeto do zero. O recomendado é fazer o teste neste projeto vazio antes de partir para modificar um sistema que já existe.

Comment: É exatamente o que estava fazendo @cigano-morrison-mendez. Passei muito tempo preso à uma mesma tecnologia, o que gostaria é de fazer todo em MVC, seria um ótimo teste <strike>mesmo já valendo R$</strike> mas ainda não aprendi o suficiente e como disse, tempo é o que não tenho. Mas vou fazer isso mesmo, vou fazer esse exemplo, e ver o que acontece.